# IPSec VPNでPingが通らない

Tags: network

ネットワーク初心者です。
現在構成図のような「Cisco WAN 実践ケーススタディ（インプレスジャパン）」に記載されている設定内容と同じ設定をGNS3というシュミレーションソフトでIPSec VPNを設定しているのですが、PC1からPC2へpingが通りません。
大変お手数ですが、原因と解決策をご教示いただけないでしょうか。
設定内容についても記載します。
よろしくお願い致します。
※access-listについては自分で追加しました。

[image: 構成図]
・WAN1

```
WAN1#show run line
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2252 bytes
     1 : !
     2 : version 12.4
     3 : service timestamps debug datetime msec
     4 : service timestamps log datetime msec
     5 : no service password-encryption
     6 : !
     7 : hostname WAN1
     8 : !
     9 : boot-start-marker
    10 : boot-end-marker
    11 : !
    12 : !
    13 : no aaa new-model
    14 : memory-size iomem 5
    15 : no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
    16 : ip cef
    17 : !
    18 : !
    19 : !
    20 : !
    21 : no ip domain lookup
    22 : !
    23 : multilink bundle-name authenticated
    24 : !
    25 : !
    26 : !
    27 : !
    28 : !
    29 : !
    30 : !
    31 : !
    32 : !
    33 : !
    34 : !
    35 : !
    36 : !
    37 : !
    38 : !
    39 : !
    40 : !
    41 : !
    42 : !
    43 : !
    44 : !
    45 : archive
    46 :  log config
    47 :   hidekeys
    48 : !
    49 : !
    50 : crypto isakmp policy 1
    51 :  encr 3des
    52 :  hash md5
    53 :  authentication pre-share
    54 : crypto isakmp key cisco address 64.100.2.1
    55 : crypto isakmp keepalive 30 periodic
    56 : !
    57 : !
    58 : crypto ipsec transform-set IPSEC esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
    59 : !
    60 : crypto map IPSECL2L 1 ipsec-isakmp
    61 :  set peer 64.100.2.1
    62 :  set transform-set IPSEC
    63 :  match address 100
    64 : !
    65 : !
    66 : !
    67 : ip tcp synwait-time 5
    68 : !
    69 : !
    70 : !
    71 : !
    72 : interface Loopback0
    73 :  ip address 64.100.1.1 255.255.255.0
    74 : !
    75 : interface FastEthernet0/0
    76 :  no ip address
    77 :  ip access-group 101 in
    78 :  ip access-group 101 out
    79 :  duplex auto
    80 :  speed auto
    81 :  pppoe enable group global
    82 :  pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
    83 : !
    84 : interface Serial0/0
    85 :  no ip address
    86 :  shutdown
    87 :  clock rate 2000000
    88 : !
    89 : interface FastEthernet0/1
    90 :  no ip address
    91 :  shutdown
    92 :  duplex auto
    93 :  speed auto
    94 : !
    95 : interface Serial0/1
    96 :  no ip address
    97 :  shutdown
    98 :  clock rate 2000000
    99 : !
   100 : interface FastEthernet1/0
   101 :  no ip address
   102 :  shutdown
   103 :  duplex auto
   104 :  speed auto
   105 : !
   106 : interface FastEthernet2/0
   107 :  ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
   108 :  ip access-group 101 in
   109 :  ip access-group 101 out
   110 :  ip tcp adjust-mss 1356
   111 :  duplex auto
   112 :  speed auto
   113 : !
   114 : interface Dialer1
   115 :  ip unnumbered Loopback0
   116 :  ip mtu 1454
   117 :  encapsulation ppp
   118 :  dialer pool 1
   119 :  dialer-group 1
   120 :  ppp authentication chap callin
   121 :  ppp chap hostname 2811@cisco.com
   122 :  ppp chap password 0 cisco
   123 :  crypto map IPSECL2L
   124 : !
   125 : ip forward-protocol nd
   126 : ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
   127 : !
   128 : !
   129 : no ip http server
   130 : no ip http secure-server
   131 : !
   132 : access-list 100 permit ip any any
   133 : access-list 101 permit ip any any
   134 : access-list 101 permit icmp any any
   135 : access-list 101 permit udp any any eq isakmp
   136 : access-list 101 permit esp any any
   137 : dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
   138 : no cdp log mismatch duplex
   139 : !
   140 : !
   141 : !
   142 : !
   143 : !
   144 : !
   145 : control-plane
   146 : !
   147 : !
   148 : !
   149 : !
   150 : !
   151 : !
   152 : !
   153 : !
   154 : !
   155 : !
   156 : gatekeeper
   157 :  shutdown
   158 : !
   159 : !
   160 : line con 0
   161 :  exec-timeout 0 0
   162 :  privilege level 15
   163 :  logging synchronous
   164 : line aux 0
   165 :  exec-timeout 0 0
   166 :  privilege level 15
   167 :  logging synchronous
   168 : line vty 0 4
   169 :  login
   170 : !
   171 : !
   172 : end
WAN1#
```

・WAN2

```
WAN2#show run line
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2252 bytes
     1 : !
     2 : version 12.4
     3 : service timestamps debug datetime msec
     4 : service timestamps log datetime msec
     5 : no service password-encryption
     6 : !
     7 : hostname WAN2
     8 : !
     9 : boot-start-marker
    10 : boot-end-marker
    11 : !
    12 : !
    13 : no aaa new-model
    14 : memory-size iomem 5
    15 : no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
    16 : ip cef
    17 : !
    18 : !
    19 : !
    20 : !
    21 : no ip domain lookup
    22 : !
    23 : multilink bundle-name authenticated
    24 : !
    25 : !
    26 : !
    27 : !
    28 : !
    29 : !
    30 : !
    31 : !
    32 : !
    33 : !
    34 : !
    35 : !
    36 : !
    37 : !
    38 : !
    39 : !
    40 : !
    41 : !
    42 : !
    43 : !
    44 : !
    45 : archive
    46 :  log config
    47 :   hidekeys
    48 : !
    49 : !
    50 : crypto isakmp policy 1
    51 :  encr 3des
    52 :  hash md5
    53 :  authentication pre-share
    54 : crypto isakmp key cisco address 64.100.1.1
    55 : crypto isakmp keepalive 30 periodic
    56 : !
    57 : !
    58 : crypto ipsec transform-set IPSEC esp-3des esp-md5-hmac
    59 : !
    60 : crypto map IPSECL2L 1 ipsec-isakmp
    61 :  set peer 64.100.1.1
    62 :  set transform-set IPSEC
    63 :  match address 100
    64 : !
    65 : !
    66 : !
    67 : ip tcp synwait-time 5
    68 : !
    69 : !
    70 : !
    71 : !
    72 : interface Loopback0
    73 :  ip address 64.100.2.1 255.255.255.0
    74 : !
    75 : interface FastEthernet0/0
    76 :  no ip address
    77 :  ip access-group 101 in
    78 :  ip access-group 101 out
    79 :  duplex auto
    80 :  speed auto
    81 :  pppoe enable group global
    82 :  pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
    83 : !
    84 : interface Serial0/0
    85 :  no ip address
    86 :  shutdown
    87 :  clock rate 2000000
    88 : !
    89 : interface FastEthernet0/1
    90 :  no ip address
    91 :  shutdown
    92 :  duplex auto
    93 :  speed auto
    94 : !
    95 : interface Serial0/1
    96 :  no ip address
    97 :  shutdown
    98 :  clock rate 2000000
    99 : !
   100 : interface FastEthernet1/0
   101 :  no ip address
   102 :  shutdown
   103 :  duplex auto
   104 :  speed auto
   105 : !
   106 : interface FastEthernet2/0
   107 :  ip address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
   108 :  ip access-group 101 in
   109 :  ip access-group 101 out
   110 :  ip tcp adjust-mss 1356
   111 :  duplex auto
   112 :  speed auto
   113 : !
   114 : interface Dialer1
   115 :  ip unnumbered Loopback0
   116 :  ip mtu 1454
   117 :  encapsulation ppp
   118 :  dialer pool 1
   119 :  dialer-group 1
   120 :  ppp authentication chap callin
   121 :  ppp chap hostname 2811@cisco.com
   122 :  ppp chap password 0 cisco
   123 :  crypto map IPSECL2L
   124 : !
   125 : ip forward-protocol nd
   126 : ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
   127 : !
   128 : !
   129 : no ip http server
   130 : no ip http secure-server
   131 : !
   132 : access-list 100 permit ip any any
   133 : access-list 101 permit ip any any
   134 : access-list 101 permit icmp any any
   135 : access-list 101 permit udp any any eq isakmp
   136 : access-list 101 permit esp any any
   137 : dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
   138 : no cdp log mismatch duplex
   139 : !
   140 : !
   141 : !
   142 : !
   143 : !
   144 : !
   145 : control-plane
   146 : !
   147 : !
   148 : !
   149 : !
   150 : !
   151 : !
   152 : !
   153 : !
   154 : !
   155 : !
   156 : gatekeeper
   157 :  shutdown
   158 : !
   159 : !
   160 : line con 0
   161 :  exec-timeout 0 0
   162 :  privilege level 15
   163 :  logging synchronous
   164 : line aux 0
   165 :  exec-timeout 0 0
   166 :  privilege level 15
   167 :  logging synchronous
   168 : line vty 0 4
   169 :  login
   170 : !
   171 : !
   172 : end
WAN2#
```

・PC-1

```
PC-1> show ip

NAME        : PC-1[1]
IP/MASK     : 192.168.1.1/24
GATEWAY     : 192.168.1.254
DNS         :
MAC         : 00:50:79:66:68:01
LPORT       : 10068
RHOST:PORT  : 127.0.0.1:10069
MTU:        : 1500

PC-1>
```

・PC-2

```
PC-2> show ip

NAME        : PC-2[1]
IP/MASK     : 192.168.2.1/24
GATEWAY     : 192.168.2.254
DNS         :
MAC         : 00:50:79:66:68:00
LPORT       : 10070
RHOST:PORT  : 127.0.0.1:10071
MTU:        : 1500

PC-2>
```

PC-1からPC-2へpingを飛ばしたときのWANルーターの挙動です。
・WAN1

```
WAN1#show crypto session
Crypto session current status

Interface: Dialer1
Session status: DOWN-NEGOTIATING
Peer: 64.100.2.1 port 500
  IKE SA: local 64.100.1.1/500 remote 64.100.2.1/500 Inactive
  IPSEC FLOW: permit ip 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
        Active SAs: 0, origin: crypto map

WAN1#show crypto isakmp sa
IPv4 Crypto ISAKMP SA
dst             src             state          conn-id slot status
64.100.2.1      64.100.1.1      MM_NO_STATE          0    0 ACTIVE

IPv6 Crypto ISAKMP SA

WAN1#show crypto isakmp policy

Global IKE policy
Protection suite of priority 1
        encryption algorithm:   Three key triple DES
        hash algorithm:         Message Digest 5
        authentication method:  Pre-Shared Key
        Diffie-Hellman group:   #1 (768 bit)
        lifetime:               86400 seconds, no volume limit
Default protection suite
        encryption algorithm:   DES - Data Encryption Standard (56 bit keys).
        hash algorithm:         Secure Hash Standard
        authentication method:  Rivest-Shamir-Adleman Signature
        Diffie-Hellman group:   #1 (768 bit)
        lifetime:               86400 seconds, no volume limit
WAN1#

WAN1#debug crypto isakmp
Crypto ISAKMP debugging is on
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): SA request profile is (NULL)
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP: Created a peer struct for 64.100.2.1, peer port 500
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP: New peer created peer = 0x66F690B8 peer_handle = 0x80000004
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP: Locking peer struct 0x66F690B8, refcount 1 for isakmp_initiator
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP: local port 500, remote port 500
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP: set new node 0 to QM_IDLE
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: insert sa successfully sa = 66C7A93C
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0):Can not start Aggressive mode, trying Main mode.
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0):found peer pre-shared key matching 64.100.2.1
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-rfc3947 ID
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-07 ID
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-03 ID
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-02 ID
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_IPSEC, IKE_SA_REQ_MM
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_READY  New State = IKE_I_MM1

*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): beginning Main Mode exchange
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 64.100.2.1 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:21:26.935: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:21:36.935: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
*Mar  1 00:21:36.935: ISAKMP (0:0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 1 of 5: retransmit phase 1
*Mar  1 00:21:36.935: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:21:36.939: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 64.100.2.1 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:21:36.939: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:21:46.939: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
*Mar  1 00:21:46.939: ISAKMP (0:0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 2 of 5: retransmit phase 1
*Mar  1 00:21:46.939: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:21:46.943: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 64.100.2.1 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:21:46.943: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:21:56.931: ISAKMP: set new node 0 to QM_IDLE
*Mar  1 00:21:56.935: ISAKMP:(0):SA is still budding. Attached new ipsec request to it. (local 64.100.1.1, remote 64.100.2.1)
*Mar  1 00:21:56.935: ISAKMP: Error while processing SA request: Failed to initialize SA
*Mar  1 00:21:56.935: ISAKMP: Error while processing KMI message 0, error 2.
*Mar  1 00:21:56.943: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
*Mar  1 00:21:56.943: ISAKMP (0:0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 3 of 5: retransmit phase 1
*Mar  1 00:21:56.943: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:21:56.947: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 64.100.2.1 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:21:56.947: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
WAN1#
*Mar  1 00:22:06.947: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE...
*Mar  1 00:22:06.947: ISAKMP (0:0): incrementing error counter on sa, attempt 4 of 5: retransmit phase 1
*Mar  1 00:22:06.947: ISAKMP:(0): retransmitting phase 1 MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:22:06.951: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to 64.100.2.1 my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Mar  1 00:22:06.951: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
WAN1#
```

・WAN2

```
WAN2#show crypto session
Crypto session current status

Interface: Dialer1
Session status: DOWN
Peer: 64.100.1.1 port 500
  IPSEC FLOW: permit ip 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
        Active SAs: 0, origin: crypto map

WAN2#show crypto isakmp sa
IPv4 Crypto ISAKMP SA
dst             src             state          conn-id slot status

IPv6 Crypto ISAKMP SA

WAN2#show crypto isakmp policy

Global IKE policy
Protection suite of priority 1
        encryption algorithm:   Three key triple DES
        hash algorithm:         Message Digest 5
        authentication method:  Pre-Shared Key
        Diffie-Hellman group:   #1 (768 bit)
        lifetime:               86400 seconds, no volume limit
Default protection suite
        encryption algorithm:   DES - Data Encryption Standard (56 bit keys).
        hash algorithm:         Secure Hash Standard
        authentication method:  Rivest-Shamir-Adleman Signature
        Diffie-Hellman group:   #1 (768 bit)
        lifetime:               86400 seconds, no volume limit
WAN2#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問される際は何を試したがダメだった、pingはどこまで飛ぶなど、調べたことを記載されたほうが良いかと思います。悪気はないのでしょうが、丸投げ方式の質問に見えます。
また、構成図にはIPアドレスや接続インターフェスの番号なども載ってるといいかと思いました。

まず、ルータ間で相互にpingが通ることを確認しましたか？
IPSecなどのオーバーレイネットワークの設定をする時は、基礎となるアンダーレイネットワークの疎通に問題ないことを確認してからにしましょう。

回答申し上げるとPPPoEの設定が問題だと思います。
両対向ともPPPoEのクライアント側の設定になっており、サーバ側がいないです。